# React js PrivateRoute show hide a dashboard Component based on JSON web token and fetch call

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need help when a user go to the URL http://localhost:3000/dashboard
if the admin already logged in before he will be able to see the Dashboard we just verify the token in his local-storage? i verify that JSON web token by sending it to the node.js app verify it if its good we send 200 status and if its bad token we send 401 status and based on the status we set the Private Route to show true or false, the fetch function its ready but i cant find a way to integrate it

this is the app files structure

```
my-app/
  README.md
  node_modules/
  package.json
  public/
    index.html
    favicon.ico
  src/
     |components/
      |Clien/
        |Home.js
        |Home.css
        |Header.js
        |Footer.js
      |admin/
        |Auth.js
        |PrivateRoute.js
        |Admin.js
        |Dashboard.js
        |Dashboard.css
      App.css
      App.js
      index.css
      index.js
      logo.svg
```

this is the function I use to check for JWT in local storage and verify the token sending it to the server get back the res  and based on the response I wanna show the dashboard or redirect to Admin login form

right now everything works fine but only if I change the isAuthenticated (in Auth Class) manually I can't find a way to do the verification based on the fetch answer from the server,
I'm not sure if I should use the function in the Auth class as a function or should I create a Component with a state and componentDidMount()

please guide me as I'm a beginner:

this is the function

```
componentDidMount(){
        //get token from local storage if there is one
        const jwttoken = localStorage.getItem('jwttoken');
        const bearer = 'Bearer '+ jwttoken;
           const data = new FormData();
           // get the website backend main url from .env
           const REACT_APP_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_URL
           fetch(`${REACT_APP_URL}/api/auth/verify`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': bearer,
                },
                body: data
           }).then( (res)=> {
               if (res.status === 401) {
                   res.json()
                   .then( (res)=> {
                       this.setState({
                        isLogedout: true,
                        })
                       localStorage.removeItem('jwttoken');
                   })
               } else if (res.status === 200) {
                   res.json()
                   .then((res)=> {
                    this.setState({
                         isLogedout: false,
                         adminEmail: res.adminEmail
                         })
                         this.props.history.push("/dashboard"); 

                   })
               }else{
                this.setState({
                    isLogedout: true,
                    })
                   localStorage.removeItem('jwttoken');
               }
           }).catch((err) => {
            // console.log(err)
            })

    }
```

this is the App Component where all routes are

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, } from "react-router-dom";
// import Auth from "./Components/Admin/Auth"


import logo from "./Components/img/logo.jpg";
import headerimg from "./Components/img/header.png";
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import Dashboard from "./Components/Admin/Dashboard";
import Articles from "./Components/Articles";
import ArticleId from "./Components/ArticleId";
import Admin from "./Components/Admin/Admin.js";
import{ PrivateRoute} from "./Components/Admin/PrivateRoute.js";


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      webiste: {
        title: "Website title",
        headerimg: headerimg,
        altheaderimg: "website header image",
        logo: logo,
        logotitle: "website logo "
      },

    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app-container">
        <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <Home {...props} setTab={"home"} />} />
        <Route exact path='/home' render={(props) => <Home {...props} setTab={"home"} />} />
        <Route path='/articles' render={(props) => <Articles {...props} setArticle={"false"} />} />
        <Route path='/article/:id' render={(props) => <ArticleId {...props.match.params} setArticle={"false"} />} />

        <Route exact path='/services' render={(props) => <Home {...props} setTab={"services"} />} />
        <Route exact path='/events' render={(props) => <Home {...props} setTab={"events"} />} />
        <Route exact path='/about' render={(props) => <Home {...props} setTab={"about"} />} />
        <Route exact path='/contact' render={(props) => <Home {...props} setTab={"contact"} />} />

        <Route exact path='/admin' component={Admin} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}  />

      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

this is the:
PrivateRoute Component

```
import React, { Component }  from  "react";
import { Route, Redirect, } from "react-router-dom";
import Auth from "./Auth"


export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
      Auth.isAuthenticated() === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to='/admin' />
    )} />
      )
}
```

this is the:
Auth class

```
class Auth {

    constructor() {
        this.authenticated = true;
    }

    login(cb) {
        this.authenticated = true;
        cb();
    }

    logout(cb) {
        this.authenticated = false;
        cb();
    }

    isAuthenticated() { 
        return this.authenticated;    

    }
}

export default new Auth();
```

this is the:
Dashboard Component sorry its huge so I'm not including everything what it matters for me how to show and hide it in the PrivateRouter

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Articles: true,
      AddArticles: false,
      Messages: false,
      Services: false,
      Events: false,
      About: false,
      AdminContact: false,
      AdminAddEvent: false,
      WebsiteInfo: false,

      isLogedin: '',

      //dynamic className
      classArticles: "admin-side-bar-button-selected",
      classAddArticle: "admin-side-bar-button",
      classEvents: "admin-side-bar-button",
      classAddEvents: "admin-side-bar-button",
      classServices: "admin-side-bar-button",
      classAbout: "admin-side-bar-button",
      classContact: "admin-side-bar-button",
      classWebsiteInfo: "admin-side-bar-button",

    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      < div key="1" className="all-dashboard-container" >

        <div className="header-dashboard">
          <AdminHeader logout={this.logout} />
        </div>

        <div className="dashboard-container">
          <div className="side-dashboard">
            <button className={this.state.classArticles} onClick={this.showArticles}>Articles</button>
            <div className="hr"></div>
            <button className={this.state.classAddArticle} onClick={this.showAddArticles}>Add Aricle</button>
            <div className="hr"></div>
            <button className={this.state.classEvents} onClick={this.showEvents}>Events </button>
            <div className="hr"></div>
            <button className={this.state.classAddEvents} onClick={this.showAdminAddEvent}>Add Events</button>
            <div className="hr"></div>
            <button className={this.state.classServices} onClick={this.showServices}>Services </button>
            <div className="hr"></div>
            <button className={this.state.classAbout} onClick={this.showAbout}>About </button>
            <div className="hr"></div>
            <button className={this.state.classContact} onClick={this.showContact}>Contact</button>
            <div className="hr"></div>
            <button className={this.state.classWebsiteInfo} onClick={this.showWebsiteInfo}>Website Info </button>
            <div className="hr"></div>
          </div>

          <div className="body-dashboard">
            <div>
              <div>
                {this.state.Articles && <div> <AdminPublishedArticles /> </div>}
              </div>

              <div>
                {this.state.AddArticles && <div> <AdminAddArticle /> </div>}
              </div>

              <div>
                {this.state.AdminAddEvent && <div> <AdminAddEvent /> </div>}
              </div>

              <div>
                {this.state.Events && <div> <AdminPublishedEvents /> </div>}
              </div>

              <div>
                {this.state.Services && <div> <AdminServices /> </div>}
              </div>

              <div>
                {this.state.About && <div> <AdminAbout /> </div>}
              </div>

              <div>
                {this.state.AdminContact && <div> <AdminContact/> </div>}
              </div>

              <div>
                {this.state.WebsiteInfo && <div> <WebsiteInfo /> </div>}
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div> <Footer/></div>

      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

this is the Admin Component its a login form

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./css/Admin.css";
import Auth from './Auth';
class Admin extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            adminEmail: '',
            password: '',
            loginError: false,
            isLogedout: null

         }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        //get token from local storage if there is one
        const jwttoken = localStorage.getItem('jwttoken');
        const bearer = 'Bearer '+ jwttoken;
           const data = new FormData();
           // get the website backend main url from .env
           const REACT_APP_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_URL
           fetch(`${REACT_APP_URL}/api/auth/verify`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': bearer,
                },
                body: data
           }).then( (res)=> {
               if (res.status === 401) {
                   res.json()
                   .then( (res)=> {
                       this.setState({
                        isLogedout: true,
                        adminEmail: res.adminEmail
                        })
                       localStorage.removeItem('jwttoken');
                   })
               } else if (res.status === 200) {
                   res.json()
                   .then((res)=> {
                    this.setState({
                         isLogedout: false,
                         adminEmail: res.adminEmail
                         })
                         this.props.history.push("/dashboard"); 

                   })
               }else{
                this.setState({
                    isLogedout: true,
                    adminEmail: res.adminEmail
                    })
                   localStorage.removeItem('jwttoken');
               }
           }).catch((err) => {
            // console.log(err)
            })

    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
           const data = new FormData();
           data.append('email', this.state.email);
           data.append('password', this.state.password);
           // get the website backend main url from .env
           const REACT_APP_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_URL
           fetch(`${REACT_APP_URL}/api/auth/login`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                   //  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                body: data
           }).then( (response)=> {
               if (response.status === 401) {
                   response.json()
                   .then( (res)=> {
                       console.log(res)
                       this.setState({ loginError: true })
                   })
               } else if (response.status === 200) {
                   response.json()
                   .then((res) => {localStorage.setItem('jwttoken', res) })
                   .then((res)=> {
                       Auth.login(()=>{
                          this.props.history.push("/dashboard"); 
                       })

                   })
               }
           }).catch((err) => {
            err.json()
            .then(console.log(err))
            })
      }

    changeEventEmail = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            email: event.target.value,
            loginError: false
          });
    }

    changeEventPassword = (event) => {
        this.setState({
             password: event.target.value,
             loginError: false
             });
      }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
             { this.state.isLogedout &&   
            <div className="admin-login-container">

                <form className="admin-login-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.changeEventEmail} value={this.state.email} required />
                    <label >Password </label>
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.changeEventPassword} value={this.state.password} required />
                    <input className="admin-login-submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
                </form>
                { this.state.loginError &&
                  <div className="admin-login-err">wrong email or password</div>
                }
            </div>  }
        </div>
         );
    }
}

export default Admin;
```

Comment: It will be really nice if you can put a working code on jsfiddle or any other online editor. This will really help all of us. Thanks -KN

Comment: or codesandbox.io

Comment: its a huge file a small CMS App with a connection to MySQL database in a Node.js server, so it will not work in jsfiddle  or codesandbox.io , but i can create a copy of it without a MySQL database

Answer (score 0):

in the Auth.js Class change the isAuthanticated to:

```
isAuthenticated() {
    //get token from local storage if there is one
    const jwttoken = localStorage.getItem('jwttoken');
    const bearer = 'Bearer ' + jwttoken;
    const data = new FormData();
    // get the website backend main url from .env
    const REACT_APP_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_URL
    fetch(`${REACT_APP_URL}/api/auth/verify`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': bearer,
        },
        body: data
    }).then(
        (response) => {
            response.json()
                .then((res) => {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        this.authenticated = true;
                    }
                    if (response.status === 401) {
                        localStorage.removeItem('jwttoken');
                        this.authenticated = false;
                    }
                })
        }
    ).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });
    return this.authenticated;
}
```

in PrivateRoute make sure you call Auth.isAuthanticated() 
so you get true or false  based on the fetch call witch will set  authenticated to true or false and it will return this.authenticated;
you are doing it the right way just check spelling

```
import React, { Component }  from  "react";
import { Route, Redirect, } from "react-router-dom";
import Auth from "./Auth"


export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
      Auth.isAuthenticated() === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to='/admin' />
    )} />
      )
}
```